# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol from imported module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, activeandroid, android-gradle-2.0

I have an android app that worked great. I have imported the ActiveAndroid project as a module because I did a change on the Model's file (I added a setId method, and that's why I can't use the gradle's version). I was using Android Studio 1.5 and gradle 1.5.0. I have updated the android studio version to 2.2 (which make me update the gradle version to 2.2.0-alpha1.
Then now, the import of active android fails. For instance:

```
import com.activeandroid.Model;
```

Detects an error: cannot resolve symbol 'Model'. What is going on? How can I solve that issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, multi-module projects fail for me as well on the new preview, so that's probably a bug. Just checking if it's already reported.

Comment: The strangest thing is than I have another module on the project which is working find

Comment: I think it may be only for transitive dependencies coming from those modules, not the modules themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was on the version 2.2 of the Android Studio, now I'm using the version 2.1.1 and its working fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1. It's reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210255

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

You can do "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option to fix this.