# Android Studio error import library

Tags: android

I have 2 projects. in first - library (android-range-seek-bar from GitHub) work fine

but after copy to second project - I have errors. Very strange errors (for me). Rebuild, clear, invalidate caches not helped :(

add dependencies in app gradle:

```
compile project(':rangeseekbar')
```

and settings.gradle is:

```
include ..., ':rangeseekbar', ...
project(':rangeseekbar').projectDir = new File('app/libs/rangeseekbar')
```

my xml is:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:rsb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
...
<org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/yourage"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.74"
                rsb:absoluteMaxValue="60"
                rsb:absoluteMinValue="14"
                rsb:activateOnDefaultValues="true"
                rsb:barHeight="2dp"
                rsb:internalPadding="2dp"
                rsb:singleThumb="true"/>
...
</ScrollView>
```

But Android studio tell me: [editor screenshot with problem] https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fPDt.jpg

so i have added from first project 3 libs: awesomevalidation, rangeseekbar, wizardpager - all this libs imported with error: [screenshot] https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8n6w.jpg

FIRST app (normal) gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile project(':fancybuttons')
    compile project(':ckchangelog')
    compile project(':appintro')
    compile project(':rangeseekbar')
    compile project(':segmentedcontrol')
    compile project(':awesomevalidation')
    compile project(':wizardpager')
    compile project(':bubbleview')
    compile project(':dialogplus')
    compile project(':processbutton')
    compile project(':androidquery')
}
```

SECOND app (problem) gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla"
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
        prod {
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.6.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.jaedongchicken:ytplayer:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'
    compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.gvillani:pinnedlist:0.9.2'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'
    compile project(':storagechooser')
    compile project(':awesomevalidation')
    compile project(':rangeseekbar')
    compile project(':wizardpager')
}
```

Comment: and last screen is [editor shows import errors] https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVhmq.jpg

(sorry, I have limits for IMG links in post)

Comment: i dont understand why on first project all OK with whis libs. All libraries import setting is identical

Comment: Are you sure your lib is in app/lib? As it doesn't seem to be the case. Try to remove `project(':rangeseekbar').projectDir = new File('app/libs/rangeseekbar')` in your settings.gradle file

Comment: I hope your build tools and SDK version in both the projects are identical .. in gradle files.

Comment: yes. all libs in folder /app/libs/  screenshot http://i.imgur.com/iRY0LSz.jpg

Comment: Thats fine ..ok can you please post your gradle files for two projects .. so we can compare..

Comment: app and libs have equals gradle config: compileSdkVersion = 25, buildToolsVersion = 25.0.3, minSdkVersion = 16, targetSdkVersion = 25

Comment: i have added normal app and bad app gradle files (at now i try to build on API 26). So, maybe to show root .gradle of both apps?

Comment: the same problem in Android Studio 2.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459524/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-from-imported-module  and in 2.3.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774143/android-studio-2-3-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-from-imported-module